# Installing Other Desktop Environments onto Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: desktop

I was trying to install budgie on top of Raspberry Pi OS. I installed the package from the terminal, but nothing has happened or changed. I rebooted the system a couple of times, and I couldn't find anything useful on the internet.

I was wondering what I need to do in order for the desktop environment to change/what I need to do to change the desktop environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a linux question, not a RPi question ... check the login screen ... it usually has an option for choosing the DM

Comment: @jsotola, I disagree. There might be some challenges specific to the Raspberry Pi to get budgie up and running. I don't know because I haven't tried it myself, but I wouldn't dismiss this question anyway.

Comment: @ethan-the-ethan, could you edit your post to include the steps you followed to install budgie?